# Заставить file_get_contents ждать получение ответа

Tags: php, json

Такая проблема: из-за того, что некое api отдаёт ответ с огромной задержкой, file_get_contents не получает ответ в отведенное время и возвращает FALSE...
В результате код

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://_api.whois.vu/?q=proverka222.com&clean',false), TRUE);
```

не может успешно выполниться. Нагуглил только вариант: 
    sleep();

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://_api.whois.vu/?q=proverka222.com&clean',false), TRUE);
sleep();
```

очевидно, что этот вариант не решает проблему, соотв. нужно именно чтобы file_get_contents ждала некоторое время /или до получения ответа. Каким образом можно заставить file_get_contents подождать пока не будет получен ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В официальной справке рекомендую сделать следующим образом

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
    'http' => array( 
        'timeout' => 60 
        ) 
    ) 
); 
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://_api.whois.vu/?q=proverka222.com&clean',false, $ctx), TRUE);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже нагуглил и реализовал именно этот вариант, но беглый тест пока что не показал что проблема решена...%)

Comment: Попробуйте указать больший таймаут. И посмотрите логи вебсервера, возможно выполнение прекращается по другой причине

Comment: Если поставить слишком большой таймаут - nginx разорвет соединение...%) Скорей всего, тут комплексная проблема, накладывается огромная задержка api (до 20 секунд) и то, что иногда отдаётся некорректный формат json. Таймаутом проблему не решить, скорей всего, придется переходить на другое api/

Answer (score 1):

> очевидно, что этот вариант не решает проблему

очевидно что `file_get_contents` вам не подходит к тому же она не совсем подходит для работы с апи. используйте cURL

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

Comment: К сожалению, использование curl на данном сервере невозможно, нужны другие варианты...?